# Confusion about install count of app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

In analytics section of Google Play developer's console, the analytics are clear to me. I am not clear regarding the public downloads count that's displayed on Google Play website and Android app. How does Google Play calculate and show that public download count? Is it by user or by device? For example if a single user installs an app on 4 devices, will the download count be incremented as 1 or 4?

Here is the screenshot for further clarification:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think **Google Play** calculates downloads per device, if we looked at **Google Play Services** it add downloads over devices for example *One User* downloaded **YouTube** over *four devices* from same **Google Account** it will count four downloads but if you downloaded **YouTube** four times from same device then it will count only *one download*, i wish this may help you at your research :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is your answer based on evidence or this is just a thought?

Comment: I collected some information about how companies track downloads but as **Google Play** is different **Google** tracks downloads over *devices* and track *activities and views* over **Google Account** also **Google** don't track downloads outside itself for example if you downloaded an app outside **Google Play** won't count it this insure that **Google Play** count over devices